# Render a content based on access permission

Tags: 7, entities, users, nodes

I have two content_types,`Type_A` and `Type_B`. I have referenced one field in `Type_B` to `Type_A` by using entity reference type. But when the particular `Type_A` node is not published,then also anonymous user is able  to view the field from `Type_B`.

To display `Type_B` contents I am using themes help and rendering all the fields. So What I want is, if the `Type_A` content is not published then that particular entity referred field in `Type_B` should not display to anonymous user. So how can I achieve that in theme file,any suggestions will be appreciated.